# How can I calculate the expected value of the sum of "n" i.i.d. variables with any distribution?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, symbolic, distributions

Particulary, I would like to find the expected value of the sum of $n$ variables distributed like ParetoDistribution[1,1.14]. For example, this works for the sum of two vars with Gamma distribution:

```
dist = GammaDistribution[1, 1];
c[n_] := Integrate[
           InverseFourierTransform[(CharacteristicFunction[dist, t])^n, t, x]*x, 
           {x, -∞, ∞}]
c[2]
```

I've tried this and it works for almost every distribution but I think that this is not a very efficent way of doing it and still doesn't work for the Pareto.

My ultimate goal is to Plot what I've called `c[n]` against `n`, to see how the expected value of the sum of `n` iid variables changes with `n`.

I need it to do it in a Monte Carlo way, in the sense that I need to simulate each variable as a random variable but with the same underlying distribution. If I calculate the mean for a `Pareto(1,1.14)` I get `8.14` but It is very uncommon that I'll get that value from a sample. So the sample mean of 2 variables is likely to be under `2*8.14`. I need to capture that randomness.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I need to capture that randomness".  If independent and identically distributed (i.i.d) random variables $X_i$ ($i=1,2,\ldots,n$) all have mean $\mu$, then the mean of the sum is simply $n\mu$.  No need for Monte Carlo.

Comment: I need sample mean of a simulated sample.

Comment: Firs figure of 
arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05495.pdf

Comment: I read the paper a bit. that figure shows a measure of the extent of that fat tail to the sum of random numbers on the vertical axis. It's not just taking the union of n- random variables. OP does not write that expression. If you are interested in the results, please at least write formulas.

Comment: You've misinterpreted Figure 1 and Figure 1 has the wrong label for the vertical axis.  The caption for the figure states that the vertical axis is the expected value of the mean deviation of the sum and NOT the mean of the sum.  The (wrong) label on the vertical axis shows the expectation of the sample mean.

Comment: I've realized that now... sorry for the inconvenience. Is there a way to do it analytically or it has to be made with Monte Carlo?

Comment: Please re-write your question and title to deal explicitly with either the expectation of the mean deviation or the $\kappa$ metric and include the reference article in the body of the question.  I understand that you're new to this forum but you need to fix the question and title so the folks here don't spend time answering questions that won't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?
my code sampled $n$ pairs, take its MeanDeviation,then get Expected Value.
I do not know the detailed procedure, but it would be reference.

```
ClearAll[dist];
fatTailMeasure := 
 Function[{n, dist}, 
  SeedRandom[
   1234]; (MeanDeviation /@ Partition[#, n] &@
     RandomVariate[dist, 1000000]) // Mean]
Function[{dst},
   fatTailMeasure[#, dst] & /@ Range[1, 10]] /@ {CauchyDistribution[],
    ParetoDistribution[1, 1.14], , StudentTDistribution[3], 
   NormalDistribution[]} // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've realized that I haven't made an important point. I need it to do it in a Monte Carlo way, in the sense that I need to simulate each variable as a random variable but with the same underlying distribution. If I calculate the mean for a Pareto(1,1.14) I get 8.14 but It is very uncommon that I'll get that value from a sample. So the sample mean of 2 variables is likely to be under 2*8.14. I need to capture that randomness.

Comment: aww,please write it in the question...

Comment: What you mean is something like this?`Histogram[
 Total /@ Partition[#, 2] &@
  RandomVariate[ParetoDistribution[1, 1.14], 1000]]`

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05495.pdf

Comment: I've found this. First figure.

Comment: Summarize the paper and Write the formula for this table.It's the role of OP. I do not think it is simply the sum of 10 random variables as you say,but also it doesn't seem to be Monte Carlo way.

Comment: I think that this is something similar to the paper, although I don't understand why it is so smooth. Thank you very much.

Comment: you're welcome.  the distribution in my chart is different from that of the paper. I think ParetoDistribution[1,1.14],you mentioned, itself is wrong...Carefully check your material.

Answer (score 2):

For the Gamma distribution:

```
dist = GammaDistribution[1, 1];
With[{n = 5},
  vars = Table[Unique[], n];
  dd = TransformedDistribution[Total[vars], Thread[vars \[Distributed] dist]]]
(*    GammaDistribution[5, 1]    *)
```

For the Pareto distribution it's a bit less obvious:

```
dist = ParetoDistribution[1, 1.14];
With[{n = 2},
  vars = Table[Unique[], n];
  dd = TransformedDistribution[Total[vars], Thread[vars \[Distributed] dist]]]
(*    complicated output that is not any simpler than what we put in    *)
```

We can, however, calculate properties of `dd`:

```
Mean[dd]
(*    16.2857    *)

PDF[dd]
(*    complicated hypergeometric formula    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The expectation is linear, so just use the fact that
$$
E\left(\sum_i X_i\right)=\sum_i E\left(X_i\right)
$$
I assume you know how to take the expectation of random variables using `Mean[dist]`.

Independence is irrelevant here. If they are *iid* it simplifies to
$$
c(n)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)=n\,E(X_1),
$$
As $c$ is linear the plot will be... linear.

```
dist = ParetoDistribution[1, 1.14]
c[n_Integer] := n Mean@dist
DiscretePlot[c[n], {n, 0, 15}]
```

[image]

If you want to do it with Monte-Carlo mean approximation you can do the following:

```
MCMean[d_, m_] := Mean[RandomVariate[d, m]];
MCMean[dist, 1000000000]

7.42469
```

which is not very good in spite of the large sample -- but that is the topic of another question: how to estimate means of Pareto distributions via MC methods.